# Multi Tenancy in SuiteCRM

Tags: crm, suitecrm

Is it possible to create a common CRM platform which will be used by different business entity in the same industry...For Eg: Create a platform for Salons wherein the business flow will be the same but contact and leads will be unique to each entity. So this is multi tenant multi business but same industry ...Is this possible by any chance in SugarCRM/SuiteCRM

Answer (score 0):

Really hard to pull of, I have seen (and worked) in many wana-bee suitecrm SaaS and they are really hard to pull of, in the end you will end up with a `forked` version to maintain the necessary changes to make it work.

Having said so, if your business scenario is simple, you can do it.

The best way to do it will be to use a custom app (what your users actually use) that interacts with the CRM using the API and using a combination of contacts-as-users, roles, and many security suite groups to make the native security take care of the AAA.